Power BI - Comparing columns with different types
I'd like to compare the below columns to get the results under Valid/Expired, below is the Format used for the columns:



Item
Format
Found In




Age
Number
Calculated Measure


Validity Period
Text
Merged Column From Source


Expiry
Date
Merged Column From Source


Transaction End of Period
Date
Calculated Measure



Input:



Age
Validity Period
Expiry
Transaction End of Period




2.42
Not Specified
03/31/2025
04/30/2024


0.00
1.00
03/31/2025
04/30/2024


3.10
3.00
03/31/2025
04/30/2024


1.09
Indefinite
03/31/2025
04/30/2024


4.38
Not Applicable
12/31/9999
04/30/2024



I use this Excel formula to get the "Valid/Expired" column, but I'm unable to replicate it in Power BI.
IF(OR([@[Expiry]]<[@[Transaction End of Period]],[@[Age]]>=[@Validity Period]),"Expired","Valid")
Output:



Age
Validity Period
Expiry
Transaction End of Period
Valid/Expired




2.42
Not Specified
03/31/2031
04/30/2024
Valid


0.50
1.00
03/31/2024
04/30/2024
Expired


3.10
3.00
02/29/2024
04/30/2024
Expired


1.09
Indefinite
03/31/2025
04/30/2024
Valid


4.38
Not Applicable
12/31/9999
04/30/2024
Valid



Note that the data is not the actual data, I've just placed dummy data close enough to replicate
I am open to either transforming the data or using calculated measures.
Thank you for the help!

you can try to create a  measure
MEASURE =
VAR vp =
    IFERROR ( MAX ( 'Table'[Validity Period] ) * 1, BLANK () )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( vp ),
        "Valid",
        IF (
            MAX ( 'Table'[Expiry] ) < [Transaction end of period]
                || [Age]
                    >= MAX ( 'Table'[Validity Period] ) * 1,
            "Expired",
            "Valid"
        )
    )

